# How to set an environment variable in Vagrant that PHP can access

Tags: php, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I want my local development environment to have an environment variable set so that my PHP app can read it.

In my Vagrantfile I have:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

    ## Set environment variables...
    echo "export APP_ENV=development" > /home/vagrant/.profile
    echo "export APP_ENV=development" > /home/vagrant/.bashrc
    ...
```

In my PHP code I added:

```
var_dump(shell_exec( 'whoami' ));
var_dump(shell_exec( 'echo $APP_ENV' ));
```

The output is:

```
string(8) "vagrant "
string(1) " "
```

I remembered to re-provision my box (many times). I'm mostly confused why the second `var_dump` isn't returning "development" but I'm especially confused why it would return a single space rather than an empty string or NULL if it's not set at all. What am I missing?

Vagrant 1.8.5

Virtualbox 5.1.30r118389

**UPDATE:**

When I SSH into the box as vagrant user, and run `$ echo $APP_ENV`, it returns "development".

I added `source /home/vagrant/.profile` to the provisioning script and PHP still can't see the var I'm setting.

**UPDATE2:**

I think Apache might be running as `www-data`. Here's some screenshots from my `phpinfo()`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You run the provisioning as `root` user which your bash is for `vagrant` user so make sure to run the provisioning as vagrant by adding `privileged: false` so the files will be owned by `vagrant` and they will be run

```
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL

    ## Set environment variables...
    echo "export APP_ENV=development" >> /home/vagrant/.profile
    echo "export APP_ENV=development" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
    ...
```

Comment: Cool! I never knew what that option did. Is there any security risk or problem with doing this?

Comment: no, there's no risk, it will just run the command as the vagrant user (actually the `config.ssh.username` which default is vagrant) rather than doing sudo command. Its not really a problem and sometimes really efficient if you want to have result such as the one you described

Comment: Ok. I added that option and provisioned again. I still get the same outputs from PHP. Even weirder... if I `$ vagrant ssh` into the box, and run `$ echo $APP_ENV` it returns "development". So I'm totally confused. (I SSH'ed in as the vagrant user)

Comment: I wonder if the trailing white space in `vagrant `  is relevant?

Comment: can you run a php script as vagrant user ? it might be that your php is runs by a web user

Comment: Can you give me some guidance on what you want me to try? I'm currently doing `vagrant up` and then visiting the web app in the browser.

Comment: just run `php <your php script file>` from the vagrant shell after you ssh into the VM

Comment: It works as expected when I do that. I see "development". I think Apache might be running as www-data. I'm adding some output from phpinfo() to the question above.

Comment: you are aware that proposed code in current form snippet wipes previous content of `.profile` and `.bashrc`? I suspect you wanted `>>` instead.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri got it! Check out my answer. If you know a better way to do it, add it to your answer and I'll accept it. Your ideas helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I was modifying /home/vagrant/.profile but Apache is running as `www-data` so here's what works:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

    ## Set environment variables...
    echo "export APP_ENV=development" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
    sudo service apache2 restart
    ...
```

I have to restart apache for the changes to take effect. If you restart apache elsewhere in your script you should be able to skip the second line.

Frédéric Henri's answer pointed me in the right direction to figure this out.

**NOTE**
One problem with the current solution is that it will add a new line to /etc/apache2/envvars *every* time you provision. So after a few iterations, I see

```
export APP_ENV=development
export APP_ENV=development
export APP_ENV=development
```

This is not ideal :-/

Comment: you can review on stack overflow or google but there's some possibility with grep/sed, https://www.google.fr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=add+a+line+to+a+file+if+it+doesn%27t+exist&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=FwcnWrbDMpDUXqzdnbgC